# asp.net web application deployment on another server iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to Deploy my ASP.Net Web Application on another Server IIS.

I already deploy it on Server but when I run that application that gives an error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'PhurtiCRM.AutoScript'.

Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AutoScript.aspx.cs" Inherits="PhurtiCRM.AutoScript" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

My C# Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AutoScript.BO;
using AutoScript.BLL;

namespace PhurtiCRM
{
    public partial class AutoScript : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably haven't built your project. Check your `bin` directory contains your assemblies.

Comment: How you deployed your application? Only aspx files? or with bin folder?

Comment: @Dai When i compile my project on my local computer it run successfully

Comment: @SelvaTS i deployed my whole application not only aspx files

Comment: @user3441151 Have you hosted in your local computer IIS and tested?

Comment: @SelvaTS can you please explain me steps of how to deploy asp.net web application project on IIS